# PHPExcel - set cell values form array

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I am pulling array data from my database for specific id and I defined cells where that values need to be stored for export.

I am calling it from my service via function and I can't find any example of how to set specific data in specific cells.

My code:

From my service..

```
 public function getExport($account)
{

    $all = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:App')->findBy([
        'account' => $account
    ]);

    $rows = [];

    $rows[] = [
        "client",
        "payer_name",
        "payer_info"
    ];

    foreach ($all as $row) {
        $client = $row->getAccount();
        $payerName = $row->getName();
        $payerInfo = $row->getInfo();

        if (empty($rows[$client])) {
            $rows[] = [
                $client,
                $payerName,
                $payerInfo
            ];
        } else {
            $rows[$client][1][] = $payerInfo;
        }
      };

    return $rows;
}
```

And in controller I prepared logic for export..

```
    public function downloadInvoice($account) {

$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($webPath);

    $rows= $this->get('app')->getExport($account);

    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A17', 'Here need to go client')
    ->setCellValue('E17', 'Here needs to go payer info etc...')

    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');
    $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
    $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'the-file.xlsx'
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

    return $response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did it:

```
 if($rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A17', $row[0])
                ->setCellValue('E17', $row[1])
                ->setCellValue('F17', $row[2])
                ->setCellValue('G17', $row[3])
                ->setCellValue('H17', $row[4]);
        }
    }
```

I eventually found it to be very easy.